# Upgrade to Kubuntu 20.04 from Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, 20.04

I am following the steps listed at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FocalUpgrades/Kubuntu but when I run the following command

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -m desktop
```

I get the following output

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release                                                                                                                                                                                                            
There is no development version of an LTS available.                                                                                                                                                                                         
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS develoment release                                                                                                                                                                                          
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.
```

Not sure why I am still cant upgrade to 20.04.1

Comment: Please add output of `sudo apt update` followed by `apt list --upgradeable` to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1265669/edit).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't an upgrade to 20.04 from 18.04 available yet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266902/why-isnt-an-upgrade-to-20-04-from-18-04-available-yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Releases dont get enabled until the weekend after the point release according to this comment https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1890936/comments/4

So the only solution is to wait out a few days.

Answer (score 1):

Me too, I can't upgrade fully updated freshly-installed Ubuntu MATE 18.04.5 LTS system without PPAs to 20.04.1 LTS.
So I have reported [bug 1890936](https://pad.lv/1890936) to LaunchPad.

At first install all updates to the current version with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then as a workaround you have to use

```
update-manager -d
```

or

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this as well. Following is what blocks me now, even after running  

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade `  
  
Checking for a new Ubuntu release  
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it is still not updated: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts