# Upgrade Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS to 20.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS to 20.04 LTS.
I know that it is only possible to upgrade from a LTS (18.04) version to (20.04), but should 18.04.5 be considered as 18.04 ? Or do I need to reinstall?

I've tried the GUI way with "Software update" which doesn't find any updates and as well these commands;

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
do-release-upgrade
```

which gives me

```
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS develoment release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.
```

Comment: 18.04 refers to a fully-upgraded 18.04 system (which currently is 18.04.5).  You are on the intended 18.04 to 20.04 upgrade path.

Comment: The 18.04 -> 20.04 path is the same as 16.04 -> 18.04 in that question... It's still early, and the *taps* haven't been turned on so prior LTS users are offered the upgrade... You can force it, or wait till it's deemed *ready*  (ready refers to a decision being made that it's fully *stable*)

Comment: I can reproduce. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1265673/66509 .

Comment: Wow I am really impressed by the fast and good answers! Thanks!(do-release-upgrade -d did it)