# Can't upgrade from Kubuntu 18.04 LTS from Kubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, 20.04, kubuntu

I still can't upgrade from 18.04.x LTS to 20.x.x LTS.  Still receiving this error:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release                                                                                                                                                                                                            
There is no development version of an LTS available.                                                                                                                                                                                         
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS develoment release                                                                                                                                                                                          
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.
```

after running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
sudo do-release-upgrade -m desktop
```

or

```
pkexec do-release-upgrade -m desktop -f DistUpgradeViewKDE
```

as mentioned [here in the Ubuntu help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FocalUpgrades/Kubuntu)

Running the following command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

returned this error message:

```
Calculating the changes

Calculating the changes

Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This was likely caused by: 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 
Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge 
package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and 
try the upgrade again. 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If 
you want to investigate this yourself the log files in 
'/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. 
Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'. 

Restoring original system state

Aborting

Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

I searched for solutions and asked people but until now no one was able to provide a clear answer.

I think that [the bug mentioned here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1890936/comments/4) by the user **the100rabh** in the question [Upgrade to Kubuntu 20.04 from Kubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265669/upgrade-to-kubuntu-20-04-from-kubuntu-18-04) is still active and was not fixed.

Please let me know if there is a solution to this problem.

Thank you.

---

@kyodake:
I already deleted any ppa entry in the `/etc/apt/` so in theory the upgrade should work, but it doesn't.

I looked into `/var/log/dist-upgrade/<date>/apt.log` and noticed that apt reported broken packages or held back packages. However, when I checked in Muon Package Manager I didn't find any broken packages or anything else.

Running the following commands returned nothing:

```
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
```

Any ideas?

Maybe I should back-up my data and do a clean install. However, I don't think this is a good solution every time when something is going wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This was likely caused by:  **Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu.**

Please **use the tool 'ppa-purge'** from the ppa-purge package **to remove software from a Launchpad PPA.**

And **try the upgrade again.**

```
grep -i ppa.launchpad.net /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
```

This will give the ppa list

The path of the PPA needed to uninstall it with ppa-purge, is the text found between ppa.launchpad.net and ubuntu.

For example, to:

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/jrm-smnt/ppa/ubuntu
```

PPA path is: jrm-smnt/ppa

So, in ppa-purge you are going to put:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:jrm-smnt/ppa
```

For each ppa.

Comment: see OP's edit for update

Comment: @kyodake: I already deleted any ppa entry in the /etc/apt/ so in theory the upgrade should work, but it doesn't.

I looked into /var/log/dist-upgrade//apt.log and noticed that apt reported broken packages or held back packages. However, when I checked in Muon Package Manager I didn't find any broken packages or anything else.  Any ideas ?
Maybe I should back-up my data and do a clean install. However, I don't think this is a good solution every time when something is going wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: @kyodake: Running the following commands returned nothing:

sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update

Comment: Seems that the bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1890936/comments/4 is still active and the changelog wasn't updated: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts

Comment: I upgraded yesterday and the problem I had was because Python2 was installed still with 18.04 so I had to remove that first using ```sudo apt-get purge python2* && sudo apt-get purge libpython2*``` before running ```do-release-upgrade```. This is probably unrelated to your issue but I thought it may be useful for anyone reading this who has a similar issue trying to upgrade

Comment: I had problems too, /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log seemed to suggest a python2 problem, I ran apt-get remove python2.7 but it didn't fix it, so I reinstalled, didn't fix it, running apt-get purge python2* then do-release-upgrade -m desktop then worked